# How to remove particular value from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove values from an array only I want in that array .html extension others I want to remove using javascript.

main.js:

```
var arr=["test1.html","power.html","main.html","save.md","kart.html","taste.txt"];

  for(var i = 0;i<arr.length; i++){
  {
     arr[i].remove("???");
  }

  console.log(arr);

 // Output should be like arr=["test1.html","power.html","main.html","kart.html"];
```

How do it?

Comment: [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: How to filter it?

Comment: Can you edit my code?

Comment: `arr = arr.filter(e => /\.html$/.test(e));`

Comment: Can you use any other way instead of filter?

Comment: @Malli Why...? `filter()` is exactly what you're looking for, why would you not want to use it?

Comment: If I use filter I am facing some other issue in IE

Comment: IE9+ *does* support `Array.prototype.filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `filter()` and `endsWith()`

```js
var arr =["test1.html","power.html","main.html","save.md","kart.html","taste.txt"];
arr = arr.filter(i => i.endsWith('.html'));
console.log(arr);
```

You can still use `for` loop with `splice()`

```js
var arr = ["test1.html","power.html","main.html","save.md","kart.html","taste.txt"];
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  if(!arr[i].endsWith('.html'))
    arr.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted tbh

Comment: Can you use any other way instead of filter?

Comment: @Malli, please check the second answer....